# If app sends a http request during termination, will the server receive it?

Tags: ios, http

I want to know that if my iOS app is terminating, if I send a HTTP request informing the server that the user is going offline, will the server get this request?

My code is below:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    NSMutableDictionary *para = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
    [para setObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserBindId"] forKey:@"unionId"];
    [para setObject:@(0) forKey:@"OnlineState"];
    [Post updateOnlineWithParameters:para withBlock:^(NSDictionary *commitResult, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate = %@", commitResult);
    }];
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try your code?

Comment: @MatthewBurke - This is generally a prudent question (and, quite frankly, the OP should have described what the result of his code was), but this is one scenario where an empirical test would not be prudent. A positive result (which is quite possible) would not necessarily mean that this pattern is safe (because it isn't). The safest way to resolve this race between the request and the termination of the app is to simply ask the OS for a little extra time to run finite-length task.

Comment: @Rob - good point. I had intended to bring up the race condition after getting more detail about what the questioner had observed. But that's not really the best approach to answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Executing Finite-Length Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) for an example of how to have an app request a little extra time (max 3 minutes, which should be more than adequate for your purposes) when the app enters background mode.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"GoingOffline" expirationHandler:^{
        // Well, we ran out of time before network request finished ... handle that however you want

        // but tell the OS that we understand, and that the background task is done

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    NSDictionary *para = @{@"unionID"     : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserBindId"],
                           @"OnlineState" : @0};

    [Post updateOnlineWithParameters:para withBlock:^(NSDictionary *commitResult, NSError *error) {
        // when done, tell the OS that the background task is done

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}
```

I tried to simplify your parameters a bit (no need for mutable dictionary ... you can use dictionary literal), so adjust that as suits your needs. But hopefully you can follow the basic idea here, if you want to do something when the app enters background, you must request permission for that.

Comment: Thank you.But,is there any different between (app enter background) and (app will terminate)? If a App terminate is terminated,will the app get 3 minutes task?

Comment: See [Execution States](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3) for discussion of app lifecycle. Bottom line, if the user just leaves your app, the above will keep app running in the background to finish network request, and it won't be suspended or terminated until then. If the user manually kills your app (e.g. double tapping home button and swiping up; or powering off device), then all bets are off and you have zero chance to guarantee request gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide a failsafe user online/offline status capability from the client side, using http requests. As Rob said, if the app is terminated (force quit or crashes e.t.c.), theres nothing you can do. The way to provide this kind of feature is to use a web socket, which is a "constant" two way communication between the phone and server. This way on the server side, you can check whether the connection was lost, which indicates that the client has gone offline. 
To create such a service yourself would take quite a long time. Luckily [Firebase](http://firebaseio.com) offer such software with a Backend as a Service. It's a godsend. [This page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html) describes how to manage offline and online status. It's as easy as pie.